# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/AppEngineDevAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

While I was trying to run a gwt project,it got errors below

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/AppEngineDevAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:280)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
```

FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main"

My JRE System Library is jre6,and I select 1.6 in Compiler compliance level,but it still the same,so what should I do?

Comment: Where you are running your programm ? on appengine ? local?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ Actually I do not know what is the difference between appengine and local,but I ran the program in my PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AppEngine requires Java 7, and the latest versions are compiled with Java 7 compliance (`-target 1.7`), so the classes can't be loaded in a Java 6 VM. This is actually what the exception tells you.

Comment: Finally I change my JRE System Library to jre7,and select Compiler compliance level to 1.6,it do not get errors,so I find it very strange..

Comment: Because the JDK 7 knows how to deal with classes compiled **for** Java 7, and the _compliance_ of your own code is independent from that (someone could theoretically take your compiled classes and run them with some version of the AppEngine classes compiled for Java 6)

Comment: Yes change to jre7 and compile project and then run..

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are the current version numbers:

```
J2SE 7 = 51,  //Note this one

J2SE 6.0 = 50,

J2SE 5.0 = 49,

JDK 1.4 = 48,

JDK 1.3 = 47,

JDK 1.2 = 46,

JDK 1.1 = 45
```

51.0 appears to be Java 7, which would mean in your case as you are using 1.6 requires you to update your java (jre and compiler)